# when I imported @ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/ngx into App Module ts, the app turn blank in serve

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm a newbee, facing the problem as you could read that on the title.

in my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { IonicSelectableModule } from 'ionic-selectable';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { NativeGeocoder } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';

import { AccessProviders } from './providers/access-providers';
import { dataService } from './providers/service';
import { NgxIonicImageViewerModule } from 'ngx-ionic-image-viewer';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Clipboard } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/clipboard/ngx';
import { FingerprintAIO } from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/ngx';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NgxIonicImageViewerModule, FormsModule, BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, IonicSelectableModule, ],
  providers: [Clipboard, BarcodeScanner, Geolocation, NativeGeocoder, AccessProviders, dataService,  { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and when I run **ionic serve** , the page just seems blank.

then the console black text appears in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'hasOwnProperty')
> at getFactoryDef (core.mjs:1413:32)
> at providerToFactory (core.mjs:6994:24)
> at providerToRecord (core.mjs:6956:25)
> at R3Injector.processProvider (core.mjs:6859:24)
> at core.mjs:6690:59
> at forEachSingleProvider (core.mjs:7030:13)
> at forEachSingleProvider (core.mjs:7027:13)
> at new R3Injector (core.mjs:6690:9)
> at createInjectorWithoutInjectorInstances (core.mjs:9998:12)
> at new NgModuleRef (core.mjs:21731:28)

humbly waiting for a solution...

Comment: reference the documentation at https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/fingerprint-aio/

Comment: or this where you will notice you do not provide it or use it in a component. https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-fingerprint-aio-biometric-authentication-scanner-example-application/

Comment: Cordova plugins that utilize android/iOS device-specific features cannot run in browser (on serve). Run it on real device and see if the problem persists. If all's ok on the device, just add a method to check if the platform is device-specific and allow the feature only then, in order to have the rest of the app code work under browser serve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to `providers: []`, so you'd have something like this :

```
providers: [Clipboard, BarcodeScanner, Geolocation, NativeGeocoder, AccessProviders, dataService,  { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },FingerprintAIO],
```